# Replace only part of a string with velocity

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

I found no way to replace only parts of a string with velocity.

Assume the following velocity template:

```
$test
something$test
$test.something
```

I want to replace all occurrences of `$test` with the string `TEST`.

I therefore use the following code:

```
  VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
  context.put("test", "TEST");
```

This is the result, I expect:

```
TEST
somethingTEST
TEST.something
```

But what I really get is:

```
TEST
somethingTEST
$test.something
```

So obviously Velocity doesn't replace a variable if there is some text after the variables name.

What can I do to replace a variable even if it is only a part of a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$test.something` is causing the problem.

It is expecting a variable `something` inside the object `test`.

Use `${test}.something` instead...

--Cheers, Jay

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face here is not 'obviously Velocity doesn't replace a variable if there is some text after the variables name'.

The symbol '$' is used to represent beginning of any line. So you have to find a way to escape that symbol in the input string so that the literal meaning of '$' is not considered

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. But I don't understand you. As I understand the '$' symbol is the start of a variable, not the beginning-of-line in velocity. As you can see from the example the second line, where the variable starts somewhere in the middel, is correctly modified.